# Android studio Firebase UI Custom listview layout

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I was wondering if the firebaseUI accepts custom layouts for listview? so if i make a layoutfile and add can i populate it as shown in documents?

e.g

```
 private ListView mListView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Find the ListView
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);

    /* 
     * Create a DatabaseReference to the data; works with standard DatabaseReference methods
     * like limitToLast() and etc.
     */
    DatabaseReference peopleReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
        .child("people");

    // Now set the adapter with a given layout
    mListView.setAdapter(new FirebaseListAdapter<Person>(this, Person.class,
            R.layout.**MYCUSTOMLISTVIEW**, peopleReference) {

        // Populate view as needed
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View view, Person person, int position) {
            ((TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.**MYCUSTOMTEXTVIEW**)).setText(person.getName());
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Yes, this is possible. You'll want to override `getItemViewType(...)` and `onCreateViewHolder(...)` as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41658860/how-to-set-multiple-layout-in-firebaserecycleradapter

Comment: Would that work if i want to add buttons to the listview?

Comment: That I would do in `onCreateViewHolder()` and then show/hide the buttons in `populateView(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does. To achieve this, you need to change this:

```
android.R.id.**MYCUSTOMTEXTVIEW**
```

with

```
R.id.**MYCUSTOMTEXTVIEW**
```

And for that you need to create a new layoout resource file named `MYCUSTOMTEXTVIEW`. When you are using `android.` it means that you are using an existing template from Android. When you are using my above code, it means that you finding by id a custom view, that you need to create yourself.

If you want to add custom views, buttons, text views and so on, you'll need to do this in your `onCreateViewHolder()` and then do whatever you want with them in `populateView()` method.